# How to set up shortcut key for Button

Tags: vb.net, access-keys

Can anyone help me understand how to set a shortcut key in the following code?
It should be Alt+X (Exit is the name of the button).
I tried `cmd_Exit.text="&Exit"`, but it printed the "&" and shortcut key was not set up.

```
Private Sub cmdExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
    'cmdExit.Capture()
    Dim response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", CType(MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, MsgBoxStyle), "Leaving?")
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then     'if yes exit the application
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

You can check that Alt+X is being pressed with the keydown event, and then call your exit sub with it:

> Note, you will need KeyPreview set to True in your main form

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.X AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
        e.Handled = True
        cmdExit_Click(sender, e) 'or cmdExit.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For the record, there is no need to use the [**`Call` keyword**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz.aspx) in this case as it is just superfluous.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Only work when I change Form behaviour property (Enabled: False). When I do that, my Form is unusable. What is the solution here?

Comment: If controls are disabled, they dont raise events

Answer (score 1):

```
set Form KeyPreview = True
```

(**Event**) Form1_KeyDown

```
If (e.KeyCode = Keys.F1) Then
    MessageBox.Show("TEST", Button1.Text)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.X AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
        e.Handled = True
        cmdExit_Click(sender, e) 'or cmdExit.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have suggested an edi to fix the code section. From your side it would be great a description of the code explaining *how* it solves the issue?